# Concurrency frameworks in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, actor, threadpoolexecutor

There are different concurrency and parallelism models in java as given below.

1. Thread per request
2. Thread Pool
3. Distributed thread Pool
4. Fork Join
5. Actor model

For Thread Pool, Distributed thread Pool and Fork Join frameworks we use ThreadPoolExecutor (java.util.concurrent package) ,IExecutorService (Hazelcat) and ForkJoinPool (java.util.concurrent package).

Is there any Class available in Java that we can use for Actor frameworks. i.e just importing the Actor framework's Class and passing Runnable objects to the framework and get work done. I have read tutorials on Akka, Scala etc but i want to know about a simple way of using a Class that can receive my Runnable tasks and execute the tasks by using Actor Framework.

Comment: I am new to Actor model. Kindly guide me where i am wrong.

Comment: Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627441/java-support-for-three-different-concurrency-models

Comment: See also [*Actor libraries and frameworks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model#Actor_libraries_and_frameworks).